# Cant send email using Gmail SMTP

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail

I have a web with contact form - I want feedback being sent to my gmail account. For this I created another, dummy gmail account for sending these messages. Code looks like this

```
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                msg.To.Add("to_mail@gmail.com");
                msg.From = new MailAddress("from_mail@gmail.com");                
                msg.Subject = "Feedback";
                msg.Body = txtName.Text + " " + txtEmail.Text + " " + txtMessage.Text;
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
                client.Port = 587;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("from_mail@gmail.com", "password");
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.EnableSsl = true;                    
                client.Send(msg);
```

This code works fine when I run it from localhost from my VS project, but once I compile it and upload to the web, its stops working with this error.

`System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.`

Does anyone have an idea what caused it and how to fix it? I already enabled access for less secure applications in my gmail account. Tried also 465 port, but that doesnt work either.

Thank a lot, Jozef

Comment: Please specify in tags language you use (C#?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found an answer. Had to click this link with my "From" Gmail account logged in.

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: Thank you to much Jozef you save my soul.

Answer (score 1):

**Possible Reason:**

> In gmail, If the current login region and the previous login region is
>   different, then gmail ask us some security questions before login. So
>   better try to login once via browser in the system which you are using
>   that C# app.